# Insert Birthdate with only YY format for period before 2000 Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, toad

I have afile where i recieve Birthdates and insert them into my Database.

the format is like the following

> 03-JUN-52

I use the following script to insert the date

```
update data."PersonBDates" set BIRTHDATE = to_date('13-SEP-47', 'DD-MON-YY');
```

and i also used

```
update data."PersonBDates" set BIRTHDATE = to_date('13-SEP-47', 'DD-MON-RR');
```

but when i check if find it 2074 not 1947.
How to insert this date into my oracle database?

Comment: The only _truly_ correct solution is to go back to the source, and force them to use 4-digit years.  20+ years ago I and legions of my colleagues were busting our butts to prevent meltdown on Jan 1, 2020.  And just last week I was reading an article about now that 2020 is hear, a lot of systems that took the cheap solution and kicked the can down the road are now reaping what they sowed.  The RR and RRRR constructs were meant to just buy time, and that time is now up.

Comment: @EdStevens, we are getting old :-). When the Y2K problem was the major IT topic all around the world the present-day junior developers were still young kids. I assume in 2050 the same problem will appear again but then we will be retired then and it is not our problem anymore.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - yes we are! ;-)  (I turn 68 later this week!) I once had an encounter with a young colleague who claimed that the whole Y2k thing was just a hoax.  I think he would have been in kindergarten in 1999.  He was a bit shocked when I told him "no, I was there and worked on the problem an while some predictions were overblown, on the whole it was a very real issue."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, `RR` should work, but - not in all cases. You'll have to fix data first because `RR` will return different values:

- for years from `00` to `49` you'll get *this century*, `20xx`, while
- `50` to `99` will return *previous century*, `19xx`

Here's an example:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select
  2    to_date('03-07-52', 'dd-mm-rr') rr1,
  3    to_date('03-07-52', 'dd-mm-yy') yy1 ,
  4    --
  5    to_date('03-07-47', 'dd-mm-rr') rr2,
  6    to_date('03-07-47', 'dd-mm-yy') yy2
  7  from dual;

RR1        YY1        RR2        YY2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
03.07.1952 03.07.2052 03.07.2047 03.07.2047

SQL>
```

As you can see, both `RR` and `YY` format mask for year `47` return `2047`.

What to do? Concatenate `19` to all years, e.g.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '03-07-52' from dual union all
  3     select '03-07-47' from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6         to_date(substr(col, 1, 6) || '19' || substr(col, -2), 'dd-mm-rrrr') result
  7                 ----------------             ---------------
  8  --             this is "03-07-"     "19"    the last 2 digits
  9  --
 10  from test;

COL      RESULT
-------- ----------
03-07-52 03.07.1952
03-07-47 03.07.1947

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

If your current inserting script works OK - which I doubt, regarding error code you mentioned in a comment:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

which means that not all input data have the same, expected & correct format of `DD-MON-YY`, then a simple way to fix birthdates might  be this:

### subtract 100 years from all dates whose year is larger than 2000

Here's how:

```
SQL> create table test (birthdate date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    select to_date('03-07-52', 'dd-mm-rr') from dual union all
  3    select to_date('03-07-47', 'dd-mm-rr') from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from test;

BIRTHDATE
----------
03.07.1952
03.07.2047

SQL> update test set
  2    birthdate = add_months(birthdate, -100 * 12)
  3    where extract (year from birthdate) > 2000;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test;

BIRTHDATE
----------
03.07.1952
03.07.1947

SQL>
```

You can modify that, of course, if there's someone who actually was born in 2000 or later.

---

As of error you got (ORA-01858), well, fixing it depends on how exactly you're entering those values into a table.

- if it was a SQL*Loader, invalid values would be rejected and stored into the `.bad` file and you could fix them and reprocess them later
- if it was using an external tables, you could use a `where` clause and omit invalid rows; for example, use `regexp_like`

Or, your best option is to make sure that **all** input values are valid dates. Then any option you choose (I mentioned previously) would work without ORA-xxxxx errors.

Comment: I've tested this script, it works perfectly fine when i write it as a script, BUT when i write it inside my scheduler to insert BD from file directly it says (ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected) !! 
the tag is <BIRTHDATE>14-MAY-84</BIRTHDATE>

Comment: I added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way of concatenating 19 to all years, as Littlefoot suggested.

```
to_date(regexp_replace('13-SEP-47', '([0-9]+$)', '19\1'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Comment: What happens to younger people born after 1999-12-31?

Comment: I've tested this script, it works perfectly fine when i write it as a script, BUT when i write it inside my scheduler to insert BD from file directly it says (ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected) !! the tag is <BIRTHDATE>14-MAY-84</BIRTHDATE> like the brevious solutions too

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to implement the solution where `01` is not considered as `1901` but `2001` or something similar (I assume that birthday year is not `1901` for any person in your system).

```
Case when substr(col, -2) < to_char(sysdate,'YY') 
     then to_date(col, 'DD-MON-YY') 
     else to_date(substr(col, 1, 6) || '19' || substr(col, -2), 'dd-mm-rrrr'
End
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I've tested this script, it works perfectly fine when i write it as a script, BUT when i write it inside my scheduler to insert BD from file directly it says (ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected) !! the tag is <BIRTHDATE>14-MAY-84</BIRTHDATE>